# Make datatype of range 0-9 in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to make a data type which can take integer values from 0 to 9 only? If yes, please tell How?

Comment: The closest you can get to that is an enum type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/*Try This Code
when you entered value more than 9 or less than 10 it show error
Hope this will help you */ 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a;
    clrscr();
    start:printf("\nEnter a No. between 0 to 9=");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if(a>9 || a<0)
    {
        printf("Please Input No. between 0 to 9");
    goto start;
    }
    else
    {
    printf("You Have Entered %d",a);
    }
        getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible to make a custom-ranged integer in C. You'll have to maintain such an invariant yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As integer overflow in C is undefined behavior, you can simply treat whatever (signed) integer type you like as having range 0-9 only. Just like with normal `int`, going outside that range will be (from your perspective) undefined behavior.